# How do I use Service Principal authentication with an Azure Machine Learning Pipeline Endpoint in C#?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-service-principal

I'm trying to call an Azure Machine Learning Pipeline Endpoint I've set up using C# & the Machine Learning REST api.

I am certain that I have the Service Principal configured correctly, as I can successfully authenticate & hit the endpoint using the `azureml-core` python sdk:

```
sp = ServicePrincipalAuthentication(
    tenant_id=tenant_id,
    service_principal_id=service_principal_id,
    service_principal_password=service_principal_password)
ws =Workspace.get(
    name=workspace_name, 
    resource_group=resource_group, 
    subscription_id=subscription_id, 
    auth=sp)

endpoint = PipelineEndpoint.get(ws, name='MyEndpoint')
endpoint.submit('Test_Experiment')
```

I'm using the following example in C# to attempt to run my endpoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-pipelines#run-a-published-pipeline-using-c

I'm attempting to fill `auth_key` with the following code:

```
var clientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_ID");
var clientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET");
var tenantId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_TENANT_ID");

var cred = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var auth_key = cred.GetToken(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(new string[] {".default" }));
```

I receive a 401 (unauthorized).

What am I am doing wrong?

- UPDATE *

I changed the 'scopes' param in the `TokenRequestContext` to look like:

```
var auth_key = cred.GetToken(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(new string[] { "http://DataTriggerApp/.default" }));
```

`http://DataTriggerApp` is one of the `servicePrincipalNames` that shows up when i query my Service Principal from the azure CLI.

Now, when I attempt to use the returned token to call the Machine Learning Pipeline Endpoint, I receive a 403 instead of a 401.  Maybe some progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, through a lot of trial-and-error I was able to come up with two ways of acquiring a token that allows me to hit my Azure Machine Learning Pipeline Endpoint through the REST api.  One uses Microsoft.Identity.Client & one uses Azure.Identity.

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

...

public static async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
{
      var clientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_ID");
      var clientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET");
      var tenantId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_TENANT_ID");

   
      var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                                                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)                                                
                                                .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, tenantId)
                                                .Build();
      var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(new string[] { "https://ml.azure.com/.default" }).ExecuteAsync();
      return result.AccessToken;
}
```

Or:

```
using Azure.Identity;
...

public static async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
{
      var clientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_ID");
      var clientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET");
      var tenantId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_TENANT_ID");


      var cred = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
      var token =  await cred.GetTokenAsync(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(new string[] { "https://ml.azure.com/.default" }));
      return token.Token;
}
```